# Reload multiple nested fields value on @object.save failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a "google forms"-like platform where a user can create a form with many questions and select their answer type to be either text fields or multiple choice, so, I made the form for answers something like this:

```
# forms partial
<% f.object.form.questions.each do |q| %>
  <% if q.text? %>
    <%= render 'text', :f => f, :q => q %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :multiple_choice do |m|%>
      <%= f.label q.questions %>
      <%= render 'forms/multiple_choice', :f => m, :q => q %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>


# _text.html.erb
<%= f.fields_for :answers, q.answers.build do |m| %>
  <%= m.input :answer, label: m.object.question %>
  <%= m.input :question_id, as: :hidden %>
<% end %>
```

This works fine for answering, however, when a user fails to fill other required fields, the form is re-rendered and the answers are not reloaded because the fields_for tag builds new answer objects again, what is the best approach to building these objects having them reload on form save failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by doing the correct approach and building the answer object at the view, and replacing:

```
<%= f.fields_for :answers, q.answers.build do |m| %>
```

with:

```
<%= f.fields_for :answers, f.object.answers.select{|a| a.question_id==q.id } do |m| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is build the objects at the 'new' action of the controller, not at the view. The 'create' action build other new object with the params and `render 'new'` safety because it no overwrites any object, just render.

Take a look at [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for) to see how send `fields_for :permission, @person.permission ...`

Comment: I understand that the best approach is to build them on the controller, I tried this, but the way the view is designed I had a problem, I instantiated a text answer for each question on the controller, but the loop in the variable made each field be replicated for each question, for example, if I had questions 1-2-3 and the answer object was built on the controller, the view would render these objects 3 times and I ended up with 9 fields on the page.

Comment: If you build the answer at the new action, and replace `q.answers.build` with `q.answer`, I think it must work.

Comment: I tried this solution but does not work because a question has_many answers, I eventually solved a bit differently, I'll post the solution shortly